# change tracking in manager after saveChanges BreezeJs

Tags: angularjs, nhibernate, breeze

I'm using Breeze and Angular on client and NHibernate on server.For business logic reasons I need to know if some object has changes after it has been saved.For that reasons I'm calling

```
manager.hasChanges(['ArrayOfTypes']);
```

In case when object is loaded from db it works as  expected(returns true/false),
but after object is saved through

```
manager.saveChanges(['ArrayOfTypes']);
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasChanges' of undefined

The error gets thrown here in breeze.js file:

```
proto._hasChangesCore = function(entityTypes) {
    entityTypes = checkEntityTypes(this, entityTypes);
    var entityGroups = getEntityGroups(this, entityTypes);

    return entityGroups.some(function (eg) {

            return eg.hasChanges();          
    });
};
```

I'm expecting 32 entityGroups to return and there are indeed 32 elements in array, but 25 of them are undefined.For now I've made a temp fix which does not feel right at all:

```
    proto._hasChangesCore = function(entityTypes) {
    entityTypes = checkEntityTypes(this, entityTypes);
    var entityGroups = getEntityGroups(this, entityTypes);

    return entityGroups.some(function (eg) {

        if (eg !== undefined) {
            return eg.hasChanges();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

Is there a way to deal with problem in other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the one or more of the entity types is not represented by an `EntityGroup` in the entity manager.  But you *should* be able to pass in any type name and not have it blow up.

This is a bug in Breeze, which is [finally fixed](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/commit/87c2a3ebf2b3f862d2b1ea20b4dfbaa9f115e9df).  The fix will be in the next release.